# Vanilla JS not this on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to style the colour of the h1 elements to black that are not "this" on click. So it will turn the h1 red on click and not this to black.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var h1Loop = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

    for(var i = 0; i < h1Loop.length; i++) {
        h1Loop[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.style.color = "red";
            not this.style.color = "black"
        });
    }
});
</script>

<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Testing</h1>
<h1>Test One</h1>
```

Comment: You need to iterate over `h1loop` inside the handler as well and compare the current loop element with `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the event listener like this.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

var h1Loop = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

for(var i = 0; i < h1Loop.length; i++) {
    h1Loop[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        for(var j = 0; j < h1Loop.length; j++) {// all header elements are changed to black
              h1Loop[i].style.color = "black"
        }
        this.style.color = "red";//clicked header element is changed to red
    });
}

});
```

when a particular header element is clicked, first the colour of all header elements are changed to black. Then the colour of clicked element is changed to Red. In this way, the clicked element alone appears in red. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. But why do we need to loop over again the H1's in order to solve this problem? A bit confused....

Comment: Because when you click a element, the colour of previously clicked element must be turned to black. But we never know which previous element has been clicked. So the only possible solution is to make all header elements black so that the previously clicked element turns to black.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the event inside the click callback:

```js
        h1Loop[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            h1Loop.forEach(el => el.style.color="black");
            this.style.color = "red";
        });
```

Comment: Why? `this` will work fine. Either way, this doesn't answer the OPs question: *"Want to style the colour of the H1 elements to black that are not "this" on click. "*

Answer (score 2):

I think below code will handle your request.

```
        h1Loop[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            // Make all black
            h1Loop.forEach(h1 => {
                 h1.style.color = "black";
            });
            // Make target h1 color red
            e.target.style.color = "red";

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the elements inside the event handler:

```
var h1Loop = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

for(var i = 0; i < h1Loop.length; i++) {
    h1Loop[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        for(var j = 0; j < h1Loop.length; j++) {
           h1Loop[j].style.color = (h1Loop[j] === this) ? "red" : "black";
        }
    });
}
```